# react get image property by using this

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react.js and JavaScript, so apologies in advance.

When I do as following in JavaScript:

```
<img 
style="cursor:pointer;" 
title="Click to edit image" 
onclick="console.log(this);" 
src="data:image/png" />
```

I would get below as a return value.
[image: JavaScript return on this]

However, if I do the same thing in React as:

```
<img
style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
title="Click to edit the diagram"
onClick={() => console.log(this)}
src="data:image/png" />
```

I would get `undefined` as the return value.

I just wanted to know why this is so, and how to get the same return property value in React as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

all attributes usually in react wrap is curly braces except strings, you can either import logo at the start of the file like this

```
import React from "react";
function ImageComponent() {
     return <img
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        title="Click to edit the diagram"
        onClick={() => console.log("Click")}
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,putYourBase64Here" />
     />
}

export default ImageComponent;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But the problem is that the src that I'm currently using is base64 data which is like 4000 char in length which is not importable like a regular image. Is there any way to just get the return value in the picture above?

Comment: try this 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{base64imagestring}" />

Comment: I try this on my local machine and it works for me and edits the code according to that hope this fix your issue.